# What is the correct way to access and manipulate pinned memory using GCHandle.Alloc()?

Tags: c#, .net, memory, garbage-collection

I'm trying to better understand what it takes to pin memory for longer periods of time. It's clear that `GCHandle.Alloc(..., GCHandleType.Pinned)` is what I need to use (over `fixed(){}`).

However, I was hoping I could get a bit of clarification on its use.

If I allocate an array and then use `GCHandle` to pin it:

```
byte[] data = new byte[10];
GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(data, GCHandleType.Pinned);
```

and if I manipulate the `data` array like so:

```
for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    data[i] = i;
}
```

am I still operating on the pinned area of memory? Or can I only access this memory via `handle.AddrOfPinnedObject()` function?

I'm sure this is probably a pretty basic question, but any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *original* object remains valid for use - since that is still named by the given variable, keep using it. A new object is *not* created and the existing object is *not* invalidated. So, yes, the code will be "operating on the pinned area of memory".

The behavior of `GCHandle.Alloc(.., GCHandleType.Pinned)` is:

- The object cannot be GC'ed before Free is called, *even if* it is no longer strongly reachable. This can cause a [true] memory leak if the handle is 'forgotten'.
- The object cannot be moved during a GC compaction cycle nor can the object be moved between GC generations. This can result in reduced GC performance/efficiency.